# how to activate second tab of Kendo UI tabstrip using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-tabstrip

I'm basically new to Angular world. But trying hard to get the phase.

What problem I now have is, how to access kendo tabstrip in my JS file and activate second tab `onClick()`.

Please note I do not want to use selectors i.e., `#tabStripID`

I'm trying to see if there is any way to do it?

pl find the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/6l8R4ggLxOA589IcbRK9?p=preview

Looking for the help.

Thanks,
Sammi

Answer (score 5):

In your HTML change

```
<div id="tabstrip" kendo-tab-strip>
```

with

```
<div id="tabstrip" kendo-tab-strip="tabstrip">
```

And change your controller as below

```
  $scope.activateSecondTab = function() {
    $scope.tabstrip.select(1);
  };
```

I saved a working example at http://embed.plnkr.co/OjKwKRjupDWwNPifqzm2/preview

Enjoy!

Comment: Ok got it working but I had it put this call into an event listener to make it work.
      `$scope.$on("kendoRendered", function (e) {
            vm.tabstrip.select(1);
        });`